# Entity framework migration "Table does not exist"

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, migration

im new to entity framework , i created my entities from reverse engineering from a Mysql database that i have created in mysqlworkbench , and then i added some foreign  keys in my entities and then i added a migration and tried to update my database but an error occured and it indicates that: **"Table 'pidev.pidev.personal' doesn't exist".**
"pidev" is the name of my database. personal is a super class for two other subclasses "candiadte" and "employee" and im using TPH as inheritance strategy.
PLZ i need some help.

Comment: You are using database first ?

Comment: There a reason why you have `pidev` twice?  Might be why the table can't be found.

Comment: @BilelChaouadi yes im using it  why?

Comment: @programmer117 yes in the server explorer "pidev" and another db called "pidevContext(myproject.web)" and when i connect my app to a database  a third one is added "pidev1" i dont know why !!!!!

Comment: Are you trying to combine the two db into one entity model?

Comment: thank you all for your replies , I SOLVED the problem in the UP() and DOWN()method in the migration file i removed the name of the database in each line like this "DropPrimaryKey("pidev.personal");" ==> DropPrimaryKey("personal");

Answer (score 4):

thank you all for your replies , I SOLVED the problem in the UP() and DOWN()method in the migration file i removed the name of the database in each line like this "DropPrimaryKey("pidev.personal");" ==> DropPrimaryKey("personal");