# MySQL 8.0.22 + EntityFramework - Table doesn't exist (database/schema twice)

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm using EntityFramework for my ASP.Net website and used MsSQL before which worked fine. Now I'm trying to migrate from MsSQL to MySQL (database got migrated from MySQL to MsSQL using the Migration Wizard of MySQL Workbench 8.0.22).
This is my setup:

- Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition 16.6.1
- Visual Studio Extension: MySQL for Visual Studio 8.0.22
- MySQL Server 8.0.22
- Connector/NET 8.0.22
- Connector/ODBC 8.0.22
- NuGet: EntityFramework 6.4.4
- NuGet: MySql.Data 8.0.22
- NuGet: MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.22

I'm able to create the entities with EntityFrameWork from my MySQL database/schema "test". But as soon as I try to work with the entities, I get the following error:

> Table 'test.test.tbl_groupspermissions' doesn't exist

I guess the problem is, that it tries to access the table "tbl_groupspermissions" with the database/schema name twice in it (test.test).

I've already checked if the name of the table is correct.

My web.config:

```
    <entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="testConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=test;user id=root;password=******;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="testMySQLEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.MySQLModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.MySQLModel.ssdl|res://*/Entities.MySQLModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;port=3306;user id=root;password=******;database=test;persistsecurityinfo=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The error appears on this part (testEntities.tbl_groupsstatus.Where):

```
    public bool hasGuestStatus(int statusId)
{
    List<tbl_groupsstatus> statis = testEntities.tbl_groupsstatus.Where(p => p.groupId == (int)ProtectedGroups.Gast).ToList();
    bool hasStatus = false;
    foreach (tbl_groupsstatus status in statis)
    {
        if (status.statusId == statusId) { hasStatus = true; }
    }
    return hasStatus;
}
```

The stacktrace tells me, that its using the correct driver:

```
    [MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'test.test.tbl_groupspermissions' doesn't exist]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +309
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) +67
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) +17
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) +110
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() +931
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +1636
   MySql.Data.EntityFramework.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +33
```

I've seen related problems with version 8.0.22 here, but without any satisfying solution for me:

[Table 'dbname.dbname.tablename' doesn't exists error in Visual Studio when adding Mysql Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64894690/table-dbname-dbname-tablename-doesnt-exists-error-in-visual-studio-when-addin)

[VS 2019 and MySQL Entity Framework duplicate database name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001562/vs-2019-and-mysql-entity-framework-duplicate-database-name/65134521#65134521)

[Schema/DB Name added 2 times in EF for MYSQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064828/schema-db-name-added-2-times-in-ef-for-mysql-db)

[Entity framework migration "Table does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894833/entity-framework-migration-table-does-not-exist)

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**
As [Bradley Grainger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23633/bradley-grainger) mentioned, its propably a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101236) of the component MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.22. Downgrade to MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.21 solved the problem for me.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is a bug in MySql.Data.EntityFramework. Unfortunately, if that's the case your best course of action is to report it at https://bugs.mysql.com/ and hope that Oracle fixes it in a future release.

Comment: It's possible this bug is already reported as https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101236; not sure if it's exactly the same or not.

Answer (score 8):

1. Close your visual studio project
2. Edit MySQLModel.edmx file with notepad
3. Replace matches in file, from Schema="Test" to Schema=""
4. Save MySQLModel.edmx file
5. Open visual studio project
6. Compile Project
7. Run Application

Comment: This helped me. I was trying to fix this issue for 3,4 days. Thank you.

Comment: This worked very well for me.  However, I suppose one must continually modify the EDMX file during development.  I am using v8.0.28, so this (disappointingly) still seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.22: [Bug 101236](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101236).

You may be able to work around it by downgrading MySql.Data.EntityFramework to 8.0.21.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue with this setup:
-MySQL Server 8.0.25
-MySQL for Visual Studio 8.0.25
-Connector/NET 8.0.25
-NuGet: EntityFramework 6.4.4
-NuGet: MySql.Data 8.0.25
-NuGet: MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.25

The solution for me was reinstalling the MySQL for Visual Studio extension and modifying the MySQLModel.edmx file like in @adamskorp answer. Maybe it was a bug on the installation or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this issue with 3 tables, while all the other were fine...

Checked the edmx File generated (DB-First-Approach), and their entries were different, for whatever reason:

Working rows:

```
<EntitySet Name="Unit" EntityType="Self.Unit" Schema="db_test" store:Type="Tables" />
<EntitySet Name="User" EntityType="Self.User" Schema="db_test" store:Type="Tables" />
<EntitySet Name="User_to_Role" EntityType="Self.User_to_Role" Schema="db_test" store:Type="Tables" />
```

And the tables causing the issues where defined as:

```
<EntitySet Name="TaggedSearchResult" EntityType="Self.TaggedSearchResult" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="db_test">
            <DefiningQuery>SELECT
`TaggedSearchResult`.`MatchPrimaryKeyValue`, 
`TaggedSearchResult`.`PredicatePrimaryKeyValue`, 
`TaggedSearchResult`.`PredicateEntityName`, 
`TaggedSearchResult`.`PredicateEntityColumn`, 
`TaggedSearchResult`.`PredicateKeyWord`
FROM `db_test.TaggedSearchResult` AS `TaggedSearchResult`</DefiningQuery>
          </EntitySet>
```

I have no idea, why these 3 tables cause a different markup - but just modifying it to look like the first representation and everything works as expected.